# NullPointerException in custom dialog 

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to develop a screen consisting of buttons where clicking a button launches a custom dialog. The dialog has a `ok` button that closes it. I wrote the following code for it but is giving me a `NullPointerException` :

```
Dialog modalDialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);

    Button modal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ModalityButton);

    modal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            modalDialog = new Dialog(Input.this);
            modalDialog.setContentView(R.layout.modality);
            modalDialog.setCancelable(true);
            Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.modality_ok);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // shows null pointer error at this line
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    modalDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            modalDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the button `ok` in the dialog's layout:

```
Button ok = (Button) modalDialog.findViewById(R.id.modality_ok);
```

Comment: what do you mean ? There is only 1 button in that layout with the id modality_ok ...

Comment: @anon Right now with `findViewById()` you are searching for the `Button` ok in the current activity layout(the one you set with `setContentView()`). To find the `Button ok` that is in the dialog's layout `R.layout.modality` you have to search for its id in that dialog.

Comment: you need to add `modalDialog` before `findViewById()`. You are searching in the activity layout, not in the dialog layout.

Comment: thanks I faced the same problem minutes ago and this was exactly the problem!!